# Finite set of points of $R^n$ is compact

Tags: calculus, general-topology, algebraic-topology

In order to show that a finite set of points of $R^n$ is compact, I just need to show that the set is closed and bounded.

First of all, since it's a finite set, I can Always pick the greatest element, and consctruct na open ball with radius greater than it. Therefore, proving that the set is bounded. (what's a better argument that 'picking the greatest element'?)

Now, to show that it's closed, I need to show that the complementar of it, is open. How to do this part?

Comment: Write the complement as the union of the open intervals $(x_i,x_i+1)$ plus the two open intervals $(-\infty,x_1)$,$(x_n,+\infty)$

Comment: @Saphrosit don't forget $x_i \in \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Any finite space is compact, as the topology is finite, and thus the only open covers are finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \notin \{x_1, \dots, x_n \}$ and $2\delta = \min_{i=1}^k d(x,x_i)$.

Then $B(x,\delta) \subset \mathbb R^n \backslash \{x_1, \dots, x_n \}$ and therefore the complement of $\{x_1, \dots, x_n \}$ is open.

Edit : as I said in my previous comment, it's even more simpler with the definition using covering : if $(U_i)$ cover $x_1, \dots, x_n$ then we can just pick the corresponding open $U_{i_1}, \dots, U_{i_n}$ which contains the points and we're done.

Answer (score 1):

A sigleton is closed because it has only one limit point (of course, the point itself), and a finite set is a finite union of singletons.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to prove that $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}$ is open.

We first prove that $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{x_i\}$ is open:

$$\mathbb{R}\setminus \{x_i\} = \bigcup_{c\neq x_i} B_{d(c,x_i)}(c)$$

So indeed $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{x_i\}$ can be expressed as an arbitrary union of open sets (open balls in this case) and therefore is open.

Since $$\mathbb{R}^n \setminus\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\} = \bigcap_{i=1}^k\mathbb{R}\setminus\{x_i\}$$

Then $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}$ is an intersection of a finite amount of open sets and therefore is open.

Answer (score 0):

Let the points be $X=\{x_1, \dots, x_n \}$.

Consider the function $f(x)=|x-x_1|^2\cdots|x-x_n|^2$, where $|x-y|$ is the Euclidean distance.

Then $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, since it is a polynomial function on the coordinates of $x$.

Now, $X=f^{-1}(0)$ and so is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fact that if $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and every sequence $x_n \in S$ with $x_n \rightarrow x$ has $x\in S$, then $S$ is closed. If $S$ is finite, then the property clearly holds, therefore $S$ is closed.